# My simple slider is repeat

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slider

First sorry for my english :(

I created simple slider, it's working,

But when double my slider is repeat,

See example for double slider

Click on next button or prev button, it's working, but all slider change images,

I used HTML ID,

See my html code:

```
<div class="slider_wrap">
    <div class="slider_content">
        <ul id="the_slider" class="slider_images">
            <li>
                <img src="slider_images/i5.jpg">
                <p class="caption">Slider</p>
            </li>
            <li>
                <img src="slider_images/i2.jpg">
                <p class="caption">Slider is free</p>
            </li>
            <li>
                <img src="slider_images/i3.jpg">
                <p class="caption">Slider is free</p>
            </li>
            <li>
                <img src="slider_images/i4.jpg">
                <p class="caption">Slider is free</p>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <i class="slider_next"></i>
        <i class="slider_prev"></i>
    </div>
</div>
```

See my jquery code:

```
jQuery(window).load(function() { 

jQuery('#the_slider li:first-child').addClass('slider_moving');
jQuery('#the_slider li').addClass('animated');
var $first  =   $('#the_slider li:first-child'),
$last   =   $('#the_slider li:last-child');

$(".slider_next").click(function () {
    var $next,
    $slider_moving = $(".slider_moving");
    $next = $slider_moving.next('li').length ? $slider_moving.next('li') : $first;

    $slider_moving.removeClass("fadeInLeft fadeInRight");
    $slider_moving.removeClass("slider_moving").fadeOut(500);

    $next.addClass('fadeInRight');
    $next.addClass('slider_moving').fadeIn(500);
});

$(".slider_prev").click(function () {
    var $prev,
    $slider_moving = $(".slider_moving");
    $prev = $slider_moving.prev('li').length ? $slider_moving.prev('li') : $last;

    $slider_moving.removeClass("fadeInRight fadeInLeft");
    $slider_moving.removeClass("slider_moving").fadeOut(500);

    $prev.addClass('fadeInLeft');
    $prev.addClass('slider_moving').fadeIn(500);
});

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that on the prev and next click events you are using classes to select the slider, and thus, you are selecting both sliders.

What you'd like to do is traverse the dom to find the parent slider element, that way you will be working only with a particular slider.

```
$nextButton = $(this);
$sliderContainer = $nextButton.closest('.perso_slider_content');
```

EDIT: As per your request here is your js code edited:

```
jQuery(window).load(function() { 
    jQuery('#the_slider li:first-child').addClass('perso_slider_moving');
    jQuery('#the_slider li').addClass('animated');

    $(".perso_slider_next").click(function () {
      var $nextButton = $(this);
      var $sliderContainer = $nextButton.closest('.perso_slider_content');
      var $first = $sliderContainer.find('li:first-child');

      var $next,
      $perso_slider_moving = $sliderContainer.find('.perso_slider_moving');
      $next = $perso_slider_moving.next('li').length ? $perso_slider_moving.next('li') : $first;

      $perso_slider_moving.removeClass("fadeInLeft fadeInRight");
      $perso_slider_moving.removeClass("perso_slider_moving").fadeOut(500);

      $next.addClass('fadeInRight');
      $next.addClass('perso_slider_moving').fadeIn(500);
    });

    $(".perso_slider_prev").click(function () {
        var $prevButton = $(this);
        var $sliderContainer = $prevButton.closest('.perso_slider_content');
        var $last = $sliderContainer.find('li:last-child');

        var $prev,
        $perso_slider_moving =  $sliderContainer.find(".perso_slider_moving");
        $prev = $perso_slider_moving.prev('li').length ? $perso_slider_moving.prev('li') : $last;

        $perso_slider_moving.removeClass("fadeInRight fadeInLeft");
        $perso_slider_moving.removeClass("perso_slider_moving").fadeOut(500);

        $prev.addClass('fadeInLeft');
        $prev.addClass('perso_slider_moving').fadeIn(500);
    });
});
```

Comment: Not working, I will send my slider files, can you help me? i wait your reply, thanks.

Comment: Sure, I'll be glad to help.

Comment: Sorry, I've actually made a mistake/typo on my answer, can you try the code again? Thanks.

Comment: okay give me your email or your twitter or any thing to I send my slider files.